# Where can I watch the original Atashin'chi with English sub?

Tags: atashinchi

[Crunchyroll](http://www.crunchyroll.com/shin-atashinchi) streams *Shin Atashin'chi* (2016), but where can I watch the original *Atashin'chi*, at least with English sub?

I live in India if it's relevant.

Comment: Note that we will only refer you to legal sources to obtain the video here. You might want to bring your question elsewhere otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Atashin'chi Official YouTube Channel](https://www.youtube.com/c/Atashinchi/featured) was launched on 30 April 2020. As of now, the channel has uploaded many episodes of the original Atashin'chi as well mini-episodes of Shin Atashin'chi. Almost all of them have English captions.

Answer (score 0):

You probably won't find anything for English. According to [Anime News Network](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=1185), there are no associated English companies listed with *ATASHIn'CHI*, unlike, say, [*Bakemonogatari*](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?ann-edition=au&id=10196) which was subbed so the website shows which English companies have licenses for it.

This is the same thing with the 2 [*ATASHIn'CHI*](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=4950) [movies](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=11658). But as you probably already know, [*Shin ATASHIn'CHI*](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=17691) is streaming on [Crunchyroll](http://www.crunchyroll.com/shin-atashinchi).

From this, I would say that the original *ATASHIn'CHI* was never officially localized in English so you're out of luck if you're looking for any official subs for it